# The Choice of Clustering Algorithm

Tags: clustering, python

I have seven columns which represent some sample that has treated with some drug over a time-series (24 hours time-series i.e 0hr , 6hr , 9hr ...24hrs). 
The table below is a snippet of data that I am describing above:

```
 col1_0hr     col2_6hr     col3_9hr    col4_12hr     col5_15hr     col6_18hr     col7_24hr     
    0.92        0.85         0.87          2            1.1           0.42      1.1
    0.57        0.8          0.88         0.92          1.09          0.22       1
      1         0.67         0.75         1.25          0.8           0.89      0.44
      0          0            0            0            0              0        0
```

Now, what I am trying to figure out is the best most fitted clustering algorithm that finds a clustering pattern for those data points that are close together across time-series? and I am trying to implement that using python.

Your help is highly appreciated it.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question sounds too close to "analyze me my data". Have attempted some methods yourself or to search literature in your field of the study where similar data were clustered?

Answer (score 1):

Define a carefully chosen distance function to capture the *medical* similarity.

Then you can use any distance based clustering, such as HAC, PAM, DBSCAN.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on distance function?

Comment: Define an appropriate $d(x,y) \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that low values indicate a similar outcome of the experiment. No algorithm can just infer what the numbers mean for *biology*. You need to provide this function when two rows are similar for your purpose.